# RedBeanPHP: Only first two store functions work

Tags: php, redbean

I am currently working on some php code using redbeanphp that should store data into database tables using four different `R::store` functions, but only the first two work, and I don't know why the other two aren't working because I made no spelling mistakes and if I try to do it with `R::storeAll` it also only works for the first two objects.

My code:

```
require "rb.php";

R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=building_framework', 'root', '');

// Books table
$books1 = R::dispense('books');

$books1->title = "Wonders of the world";
$books1->author_id = "1";
$books1->publisher_id = "1";

$books2 = R::dispense('books');

$books2->title = "Math for dummy's";
$books2->author_id = "1";
$books2->publisher_id = "1";

// Author table
$author = R::dispense('author');

$author->id = "1";
$author->author = "Francesco Boccia";

// Publisher table
$publisher = R::dispense('publisher');

$publisher->id = "1";
$publisher->publisher = "Metro Books";

$store1 = R::store($books1);
$store2 = R::store($books2);
$store3 = R::store($author);
$store4 = R::store($publisher);

echo $store1;
echo $store2;
echo $store3;
echo $store4;
```

When I execute it, all the tables are getting made, but only in the `books` table, data is stored and not in the other two. Can someone please help me fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know my mistake. I added an `id` for `author` and for `publisher` but the id gets added by redbean itself, so there was no need for that.